# No Internet Connection after unlock device iPhone

Tags: ios

I am calling a few web-services in my iphone app in the `viewWillAppear` method (which is necessary).

What happened is when I lock the device and then unlock it,it shows me an alert **no Internet connection** which is actually the alert I am using when no Wifi is available.

I don't know how to tackle with this issue. Kindly help me on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long the device was locked, it may need to reacquire a connection to a cell tower or WiFi access point.  There is no way for you to code around this hardware limitation, but you can adapt to how your app handles it.

One solution would be to store the desired `viewWillAppear` action in a block ivar, and then check for the presence of an internet connection before executing the block.  If you have one, then execute the block like normal.  If you don't have one, wait for a [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) ([a more modern version](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) is available also) notification to indicate that you have a connection again and then execute the block.  Note that if the user is in an area without a connection then this block could potentially never execute.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do if the device loses internet connection except to make sure you recheck after coming back to the app.You should do that in AppDelegate.m method :

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and then post a notification (1) and add an observer (2) to it in the class that you need this information. 
E.g:

```
(1) [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kConnectionChangedNotification object:nil];

(2) [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToCallIfConnectionChanged:) name:kConnectionChangedNotification object:nil];
```